# How does Meteor keep client from manually changing their user _id or altering their login status

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I found meteor a couple weeks ago, and was really excited. When I found out about angular-meteor, I was practically ecstatic. However with all the data binding, I'm not exactly sure how authentication works, and I need to know that in order to use it on any production system. I've read several blog posts and SO questions, but I'm still not sure how it works, and I would appreciate it if someone could explain it all so that I can be confident I'm using the system correctly.

My main question revolves around this standard function you see that governs publishing, taken straight from the Angular-Meteor tutorial.

```js
Meteor.publish("users",function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({},{fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});
```

Now what if a user changes his `userId` in the console on the client?  It seems like that change would be synced back to the server, and the server would think he was someone else. I would assume that there is a way that `this.userId` is kept separate from the variable on the client side called in `Meteor.userId()` so that it can't be changed. However I would like to get some confirmation that there is indeed a separation, and how that separation works so I can be confident in using meteor authentication.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the data change on the front-end does not automatically get allowed by the server. Make sure you have removed the `insecure` package. After that, you need to manually specify which data changes are allowed, e.g.:

```
Parties.allow({
  update: function (userId, party) {
    return (userId == party.owner);
  }
});
```

Would only allow the owner of a party to update the details of the party. Here meteor checks that the user is indeed the owner by comparing the `userId` (which is the id of the currently logged in user) with the `owner` field of the party.

All this happens server side, so the user cannot temper with this.

In your case, unless you somehow allow a user to edit their id by explicitly creating an `allow` rule on the `Meteor.users` collection -- why would you? -- the issue you are concerned with is not possible.

The [Data and Security](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/dataandsecurity) section of the documentation has more detail on this.

Comment: That link to data and security is exactly what I was looking for.